# where Interrupt saves the address of the current activity to resume it after executing the interrupt handler

Tags: embedded, interrupt

"When an interrupt is occurred, The processor responds by suspending its current activities, saving its state, and executing a function called an interrupt handler"

> The question is where the processor save the address of the current
>   activities to resume it after executing the interrupt handler?

Comment: usually a stack but it depends on what architecture you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heavily depends on the architecture.
A couple of approaches come to mind (I'm sure there are more):

- Push essential registers into the current stack (e.g: Instruction Pointer), then jump to the exception handler. The exception handler is then responsible to preserve any other registers it needs to use. I believe this is the approach done by x86 CPUs. I'm just not sure if it pushes all registers by default, or the essential ones.
- The CPU has a different register set depending on the CPU mode. (e.g:: User mode, Interrupt Mode). Essentially, when an interrupt occurs, it starts using a different register set. For example, ARM cpus do this, although they don't use a full register set per CPU mode. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture#Registers
- Some ancient cpus have the register set in RAM itself, so switching context is just changing the location of the register set in memory. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments_TMS9900#Architecture. This approach is not feasible if the RAM is way slower than the CPU itself. But it's still feasible for simulated computers. For example, my hobby project (A fully simulated computer) uses this approach. The kernel setups up a different register set per application.https://bitbucket.org/ruifig/g4devkit. Although I might change to a different solution at some point.

Comment: "RAM is way way slower than the CPU itself" - That is nonsense for small low-power MCUs.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, I forgot that one case. Thanks :) Know of any modern low-power CPUs that do that?

Comment: There are more variants that that. The question is far too broad to be on-topic here! "Know of any modern low-power CPUs that do that" - Yes! "Modern" is a nonsense criterion. There still is a large number of 8051 derivates. In total, they might still be the majority of sold units.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the architecture you are pertaining to. But usually the processor itself pushes the current program counter in the moment of interruption into the current stack. The return of the interrupt will then fetch those stacked PC information and returns to the normal program flow. E.g. architectures that push the PC to the stack: Atmel AVR, ARM Cortex-M, PowerPC.

Atmel AVR: http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_RETI.html

ARM Cortex-M: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/Babefdjc.html